# inserting string from pandas dataframe gives TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting

Tags: python, typeerror

**Set-up**

Using python to access the Shopify API of various shops.

Currently, there's only a need to connect with 1 shop, but more shops will follow in the future so I want to prepare the code for it to be able to handle multiple shops in the future.

---

**Code**

```
import shopify
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@myshopsurl.com/admin/api/%s" % (API_KEY, PASSWORD, API_VERSION)
shopify.ShopifyResource.set_site(shop_url)
```

which connects correctly to `myshopsurl.com`.

Defining the `shop_url` like below also works fine,

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@myshopsurl.com/admin/api/%s" % (keys['API_KEY'][0], keys['PASSWORD'][0], API_VERSION)
```

where I pull `myshopsurl.com`'s `API_KEY` and `PASSWORD` from a prior constructed `keys` panda dataframe.

---

**Issue**

Now, if I want to pull `myshopsurl.com`'s url (i.e. `'myshopsurl.com'`) from `keys` like so,

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@" + keys['url'][0] + "/admin/api/%s" % (keys['API_KEY'][0], keys['PASSWORD'][0], API_VERSION)
```

then I receive a `TypeError: not all arguments converted during string formatting`.

---

**Question**

How do correctly insert `myshopsurl.com`'s url from `keys` in the `shop_url` variable?

Comment: Why not use `shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s/admin/api/%s" % (keys['API_KEY'][0], keys['PASSWORD'][0], keys['url'][0], API_VERSION)` I guess it would fail depending on the sequence in which the operators are evaluated in python

Comment: That solves it! Thanks a lot.

Answer (score 0):

Following [@Evan](https://stackoverflow.com/users/499280/evan)'s comment,

```
shop_url = "https://%s:%s@%s/admin/api/%s" % (keys['API_KEY'][0], keys['PASSWORD'][0], keys['url'][0], API_VERSION)
```

solves it.